# R: use strsplit transform to list that is not length of 1

Tags: r, strsplit

I was writing some code that need to inspect individual characters in a input string. I want to know whether there were numbers in string, and use strsplit to split the character into list. Then, use any() to check the numbers  (the limitation is that I can't use grepl :(

```
b<-"Idontknow456"
b<-strsplit(b,"")
length(b)
any(6%in%b)

c<-list("d","t","5")
length(c)
any(5%in%c)
```

the result

```
  1
  FALSE
  3
  TRUE
```

May I ask how should I modify my code, so that I can split individual characters to inspect them?

Comment: You may need `unlist` or `[[1]]` to get a vector back i.e `b<-strsplit(b,"")[[1]]`

Comment: strsplit  returns list, try `any("6" %in% unlist(b))`

Comment: But the solution is regex, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33393112/680068

Comment: Maybe you can also try: `utf8ToInt("6") %in% utf8ToInt(b)`

Comment: but length()  should return the number of items of a list , according to the doc I found ... :? https://www.google.com/search?q=length+of+a+list+in+r ; https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-use-the-length-function-to-get-the-length-of-a-list-in-r  So why doesn't it for the list returned by strsplit ?