# need to compare addresses across several columns and return the most complete - fuzzy join, etc

Tags: r, street-address, fuzzyjoin

I have two files of customer records I need to merge.   The addresses don't always match because they are not the same address, or there is part missing.   I have tried fuzzy join without success.   I basically need to compare 4 columns and assemble a complete address.   Example below   For example the first record I need to pull out 320th 15th NW, the 6th record down with II need 614 W Superior St.   The address parts are spread across these 4 columns.   Any help you could provide would be excellent.

[image: data]

Comment: You could try creating some string checks. E.g. test which column contains some of 'street' or 'ST' or 'ave' or a number followed by st/nd/rd/th. Or sth. Like that and then pull the info from that respective column. It should probably work in 95% of the cases.

Comment: Also please share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Complementing @deschen comment--in addition to scannign for e.g. "street", "st", "ave", you might require that the string includes a number. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393112/check-if-a-string-contains-at-least-one-numeric-character-in-r) for examples of how to do that.